# Where is the intel sgx psw and making intel sgx work with ubunut 18.04

Tags: installation, intel, sgx

I've tried following the intel instructions to install sgx, but it requires the sgx_linux_x64_psw_.bin file, which i cannot find anywhere. I've got the driver installer (sgx_linux_x64_driver_1.35.bin) and the sdk installer(sgx_linux_x64_sdk_2.10.100.2.bin), intel seems not to have a psw for linux? If so, how do i properly work with sgx? I tried simply executing the driver and sdk .bin files, but the sample code in the sdk would not compile (after make SGX_MODE=SIM), even after setting the sgxsdk directory to /opt/intel/sgxsdk. I'd get the following compile error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libsgx_uae_service_sim.so, needed by /opt/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/libsgx_urts_sim.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/libsgx_urts_sim.so: undefined reference to `get_launch_token'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:235: recipe for target 'app' failed
make[1]: * [app] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/intel/sgxsdk/SampleCode/SampleEnclave'
Makefile:180: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: * [all] Error 2
```

Any help with either issue would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So at least in my case, it seems the issue was that I was A, using a virtual machine, which can ONLY run in simulation mode, so getting a fully working version of sgx is impossible. Secondly, I was using an outdated installation guide, for anyone else trying to use this stuff, make sure to get the installation guide from the intel download page along with the version you are downloading.

Answer (score 0):

download source code from https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx, compile according to the instructions and then install psw.